# Using 'findAndModify' on mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I use mongodb on my site.When I try to run "findAndModify‬" function I always get that doc is 'undefined':

```
function counter(name) {
    var doc = this.db.collection('counter').findAndModify(
                { query: { _id: name }, 
                  update: { $inc: { next: 1} }, 
                  new: true, 
                  upsert: true });

    return doc.next;
}
```

Q: *What am I missing?*

Comment: What release of MongoDB are you running currently and with what driver? What are your results if you try this through the shell?

Comment: I use 2.0.3 .If I check in shell it works

Answer (score 2):

I just had this problem trying to implement the same counter sample code from the MongoDB docs.

If you're using the [mongojs](https://github.com/mafintosh/mongojs) driver you need to use a callback as that function doesn't return anything:

```
this.db.collection('counter').findAndModify({
    query: { _id: name }, 
    update: { $inc: { next: 1} }, 
    new: true, 
    upsert: true 
    },
    function(err, doc){
        console.log('the id is: '+doc.next);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You not missed anything, with upsert equal to true findAndModify should always return document.. Even if no matches by query.

But, there is limitations with sharding and findAndModify -- your query should always contains shard key, mb this is an issue.

Also this command available for mongodb that has version >= 1.3. If you use old mongodb, just update it to latest release (2.0.3) and it should work. (I've tested on 1.8 and 2.0)

Answer (score -3):

After breaking my head for quite a long time I change sort to 1 and it worked.....

```
counters.findAndModify({ _id: { $eq: "virtualcurrency" } }, { '_id': 1 }, { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, { new: true }, function (err, result) {
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the problem described in the question.